# Python: how to extract the last instance of the same string.

Tags: python, string

so I am doing a python project where I have to read a csv file, and extract values from specific rows and columns. So I do the standard .loc function to get this information. An issue I am running into is that for one column there is a specific string that is listed several times, and at the very bottom of the csv file is the total of all those values for that string. However, the string name is exactly the same. I cannot manually change this as there are hundreds of files for this in the same format. What should I do ? Should I use some sort of forloop

Comment: Do you already have existing code?  StackOverflow is not a place where we write code for you, but help you fix bugs in your OWN code.  Yes, you will most certainly need a for loop, probably a while loop, to do this.  But I can't write code for you since i have no idea the other requirements of your project, how you are storing things, if you want it exported to a file, runtime limitations, what version of python you are using (big difference in some case), what external libraries you have access to, etc.  We need more information, and specifically actual code to help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Dummy example below:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1]
b = a+1
b = [x+1 for x in a]
df = pd.DataFrame({'One':a, 'Two':b})
your_indexes = df.index[df['One'] == 1].tolist()
```

If, from then on you want to edit the values at those indexes, either use the `df.iloc` function, either do it from the beginning without extracting indices, as follows:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows()
    if row['InterestingColumn'] == 'TheProblemString':
        df['InterestingColumn'][index] = 'ReplacementString'
```

I hope this answers your badly formulated question.
And next time provide the code you wrote, otherwise people will just say you want to be spoonfed a solution and simply downvote and not answer your question.